# Restore purchase for non renewing in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Restore purchase for non renewing in app purchase need to invoke -paymentQueue:updatedTransactions . But its not working in my case ?

In Restore Button clicked i put below code

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

After successful restore its invoking below function

```
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

But

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

is not invoked . Any idea why ?

Comment: You should really add some more details if you want anybody to be able helping you...

Comment: have given more details. please help